# Who can qualify for the Australian Open?

Tags: tennis, atp, wta, grand-slam

I apologise if this question may sound ridiculous.
 I would like to know if there are any limitations to qualify for the Australian Open.

For example, to qualify for the WTA Finals, WTA players compete throughout the year in over 53 tournaments plus the Slams. By doing so, players earn ranking points and ONLY the first 7 (or 8) top players can have access to the WTA finals.

Is there a similar rule also for the Australian Open?

Comment: I would assume that you would need to be a registered WTA or ATP player in order to qualify, there is also likely a fee to participate. I'm not sure how else they would narrow down the field of players but if I were to outright guess I'd say there's probably a minimum number of ATP or WTA points you would need to have in order to qualify for the right to qualify for the tournament.

Answer (score 1):

128 players compete in the singles main draw of Australian Open.

- 104 spots are given to players with highest ATP/WTA ranking at that moment. If some of the 104 top players will not participate, next top ranked players will replace them.
- 16 spots are given to qualification winners (Q). Players qualify to qualification based on their ranking, like in main draw. There are 16 qualification brackets consisting of 3 rounds. Player who wins all 3 rounds in a bracket will qualify to the main draw. Additionally, if some players from the main draw will not be able to play the first round due to an illness or so, lucky losers will replace them (LL). Lucky loser is a player who lost in qualification. Lucky loser are chosen based on qualification round they have been eliminated in (higher is better) and then based on their ranking. 119 spots in qualification are given based on ranking, remaining 9 are given to wildcards.
- 8 spots are given to wildcards (WC). Tournament has the right to give a wildcard to any player. Usually they are given to young talents, local players, or can be earned by winning some small wildcard tournament playoff.
- additionally, players can use theirs protected rankings to qualify for the main draw (PR)
- in some situations, special exempt (SE) spots in the main draw are given to players who signed up for qualification but are still playing some late rounds in other tournament and due to it could not compete in the qualification